# A kind of – German Expressions

Tags: expression

Whenever I try to say something like ‘A type of car’, or ‘a type of food’, I end up saying

‘eine Art + *nominative singular*’ or

‘eine Art von *nominative singular*’

but I’m not really sure about it. What is the correct way to say it?

Comment: I edited *ein Art* to *eine Art,* since the grammatical gender of *Art* is female and this is not the focus of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both expressions are correct per se, but they have different meanings:

> Ein Cabrio ist eine sportliche Art von Auto.

or

> Ein Cabrio ist eine sportliche Autoart.

The statement here is that convertibles (Cabrios) are in fact cars (Autos) and a subcategory of cars.

But

> "Fotografieren ist eine Art Meditation."

Here the word *Art* means *"similar to"* like the English *"kind of."* Sometimes the difference to "Art von" is not as clear and sometimes it's the same. It depends on the context.

You can use the word *Art* also in combination with a definite article, like in

> Mir gefällt deine Art der Gesprächsführung.

Here *Art* means "the way" (in German *die Weise*).

Comment: Art cannot mean "similar to" in written German. This would be very bad style. In spoken German, where exactness levels are lower, one might encounter this.

Comment: @ Toscho: I tend to disagree. Of course, it is less common in written German since this kind of vagueness is not needed in written language that often, but it certainly is not very bad style (if used where appropriate). On [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=%22eine+Art%22) you can find various examples from newspapers where the expression is used.

Comment: Praktisch würde man aber eher sagen `Ein Cabrio ist ein sportliches Auto.` Ganz schwach ist das `von`. `Ein Cabrio ist eine sportliche Art Auto.` einfach ohne von ist schon deutlich besser. Das Auto kam `von` links.